# How to assign None to object reference in python

Tags: python, oop, pass-by-reference

I am a newbie to python, got little confused over output of following code.

```
class obj:
    def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data

o1 = obj(2)
o2 = o1

def func1(obj):
    obj.data = 5


func1(o1)
print(o1.data)
print(o2.data)
o2 = None
print(o1)
print(o2)
```

Output:

```
5
5
<__main__.obj instance at 0x7f7f6b5e63f8>
None
```

Shouldn't o1 object become 'None' too??

Comment: You should probably read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html - assignment doesn't affect the *value*, just the *identifier*.

Comment: "Shouldn't o1 object become 'None' too?" No.

Comment: `o1` isn't an object; it's a *name* referring to an object. Changing what the name `o2` references has no effect on the object that `o2` *used* to refer to (which is what `o1` currently refers to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`o1` shouldn't be `None`.

when you execute the line `o2 = None`, `o2` no longer refers to the `o1` object. It now refers to the `None` object. `o1` and `o2` now refer two different objects in memory, as shown by the `id` function (different identity, `id` returns the object memory address in `CPython`)

```
print (id(o1)) # 140282748479024
print (id(o2)) # 140282748479024
o2 = None
print (id(o1)) # 140282748479024
print (id(o2)) # 140282774063376
```

Comment: The memory address of ``o2`` is *not* changed. The bound object is changed, which has a different address practically by definition.

Answer (score 2):

Variables in Python are *names of objects*, not *locations of memory* as in C++. Reassigning a name merely changes what the name refers to; it does not change the referent or other aliases.

---

The closest equivalent is a pointer: In CPython, assigning a name as in `o2 = o1` effectively means `PyObject *o2 = *o1`. The address is *copied* from one name to the other. There is no direct relation between names after assignments - they just happen to still refer to the same object.

```
>>> o1 = {1, 2, 3}
>>> o2 = o1
>>> print(id(o1), id(o2))  # the *referents* of o1 and o2 are at the same memory location
4444160520 4444160520
```

When two names refer to the same object, they show the same state of the object - after all, there is only one state. This is why changing `o1.data` was visible via `o2` as well - the *object* that both `o2` and `o1` refer to was modified.

```
>>> o1.add(16)
>>> print(o1, o2)  # still the same referent, should have the same state
{16, 1, 2, 3} {16, 1, 2, 3}
>>> print(id(o1), id(o2))  # both still have the same referent
4444160520 4444160520
```

The trick is that while `o1` and `o2` are separate, members such as `o1.data` and `o2.data` are not! Each top-level name is a separate entity. However, attributes and the like are relative to their object!

---

When you reassign, that changes only the name assigned to. Remember that `o2` *copied* the reference from `o1` - there is no relation that could be affected by changing the name `o1`.

```
>>> o1 = None
>>> print(o1, o2)  # not the same referent anymore
None {16, 1, 2, 3}
>>> print(id(o1), id(o2))  # only o2 still refers to the same referent
4436169032 4444160520
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `o2 = None` effectively reassigns as a different object than `o1`.  Observe:

```
>>> o1 = obj(2)
>>> id(o1)
155034832  
>>> o2 = o1
>>> id(o2)
155034832  # same ID as o1
>>> o1 is o2
True       # the objects are identical
```

But once you reassign `o2`:

```
>>> o2 = None
>>> id(o2)
262150788  # ID has now changed
>>> o1 is o2
False      # the objects are now different.
```

Once you reassign, the objects have no relation to each other (unless tied by other means) and reasonably you should not expect them to behave the same.